# Why does illegalArgumentException get thrown when I use createBufferStrategy(3)?

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception

I'm starting to create a game using Java. In my render() method, I have a buffer strategy, with three buffers. However, when I run it, I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.CGLGraphicsConfig.createCompatibleImage(CGLGraphicsConfig.java:200)
    at java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(GraphicsConfiguration.java:178)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.getBackupImage(SunVolatileImage.java:236)
    at sun.awt.image.VolatileSurfaceManager.getBackupSurface(VolatileSurfaceManager.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.VolatileSurfaceManager.initialize(VolatileSurfaceManager.java:126)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.<init>(SunVolatileImage.java:88)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.<init>(SunVolatileImage.java:98)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.<init>(SunVolatileImage.java:109)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.CGLGraphicsConfig.createBackBufferImage(CGLGraphicsConfig.java:356)
    at sun.lwawt.LWCanvasPeer.createBuffers(LWCanvasPeer.java:62)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:4016)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3956)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4479)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3833)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:194)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3756)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:169)
    at com.game.framework.Game.render(Game.java:79)
    at com.game.framework.Game.run(Game.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is the full class with the render() method:

```
package com.game.framework;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2956560507546666478L;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    public Game() {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "UNKNOWN", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;

        int frames = 0;

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();

            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }

            if (running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() { }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Here is the other class in my game:

```
package com.game.framework;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 70937078350109973L;

    public Window (int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(game);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but it is quite frustrating and I cannot continue until the problem is solved. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Why does the code have 2 separate classes that extend `Canvas`?  BTW - I've done lots of animations in Swing.  Never bothered to use a `Canvas` or `BufferStrategy`, and they all worked out (fast and) fine.

Comment: Well, I tried your exact code posted here and it just prints the FPS. No errors and it can create the `BufferStrategy`. (I'm using Java 7)

Comment: Any clue why it might not be working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I've found a possible reason why your code works for me, but not for you. I'm using Direct 3D to do the rendering and you're using OpenGL.

The D3D classes also using [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/java2d/d3d/D3DGraphicsConfig.java#D3DGraphicsConfig.createBackBuffer%28sun.java2d.d3d.WComponentPeer%29) to create the `BufferStrategy`:

```
public VolatileImage createBackBuffer(WComponentPeer peer) {
    Component target = (Component)peer.getTarget();
    // it is possible for the component to have size 0x0, adjust it to
    // be at least 1x1 to avoid IAE
    int w = Math.max(1, target.getWidth());
    int h = Math.max(1, target.getHeight());
    return new SunVolatileImage(target, w, h, Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

As you can see, it sets the width and height to at least `1` to avoid an `IllegalArgumentException`.

The [OpenGL version of that class](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17983127/#l-335) does not:

```
@Override
public VolatileImage createBackBufferImage(Component target,
                                           long backBuffer) {
    return new SunVolatileImage(target,
                                target.getWidth(), target.getHeight(),
                                Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

So if you still want to use OpenGl, then you need to bypass the short time, where the size of the Canvas isn't set yet** (i.e. width and height are `0`) by yourself:

```
private void render() {
    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
}
```

** It seems that there is a very short time where the `Game` canvas doesn't "has" his correct size. It size is `0x0` there, but will later be updated to `634x449` (after around 3 iterations of your game loop).

Comment: I tried this, but the exception is still thrown, so it must be caused by something else.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I used the code you provided and it worked fine. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @zjuventus14 Glad it helped. Please consider accepting this answer as correct, by ticking the check mark beneath the vote counter. And you can remove the first comment under this answer, because it is obsolete now :).

Comment: I did :). Also, based on this code I came up with an easier fix 'this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);' at the beginning of my run() method before calling render(). Thank you for your help though.